# How exactly does a lemma differ from another type of proposition (like a theorem or corollary)?

Tags: terminology

How exactly does a lemma differ from another type of proposition (like a theorem or corollary)?

I think it is that lemmas are used to help prove theorems and coroallary are specific cases of theorems. Is this correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lemma vs. Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111428/lemma-vs-theorem)

Answer (score 5):

There is no *formal* difference between a "theorem" and "lemma".

As you have noticed, propositions tend to be called "lemmas" when the author's main purpose in proving them is as a stepping stone to proving something more interesting. But ultimately is is subjective what one considers "interesting" enough to be called a theorem.

There are also results that are important enough to have capitalized names and *nevertheless* are called lemmas, such as for example **Zorn's lemma**. This is sometimes a pure accident of history, but also sometimes to suggest that whereas the result does not look particularly interesting on its surface, it is a useful component for proving more substantial propositions.

Comment: Le theoreme de Zorn, Zorn's lemma , a bit of history, perhaps of interest.https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma